# How to check programmatically if a security update is applied in Android

Tags: android

I want to know how to check programmatically if a security update is applied.

I'm testing my application on Galaxy S6 Edge.
On my Galaxy S6 Edge, Build.VERSION.SECURITY_PATCH is "2017-01-01", but it works like the security update in 2016-03-01 is not applied.
Specifically, "Remote Denial of Service Vulnerability in Bluetooth"(CVE-2016-0830) is not fixed, I think.
This is the URL of the update: https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2016-03-01.html

I want to make sure the security update is applied or not.
And I want to fix my application to programmatically check the security update is applied or not.

Could you tell me how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried in terms of code?